# Nested pagination in facebook graph api while using php-sdk-v4

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to get all users who likes a specific post on a feed. I am using `facebook/php-sdk-v4` . There is no problem on getting next page for feed. However when I use next function to get next users who liked that post in inner loop it gives

> Error:Caused by: Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException
>   Subfields are not supported by feed.

In `FacebookRequest.php` I disabled `appsecret_proof`, maybe it is related to this security issue. If I don't disable, it gives now invalid `appsecret_proof` despite `v5.0` sdk already generates `appsecret_proof` internally at the line `70 of Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken.php`.
Without `appsecret_proof` I am able to request but in some cases like batch query or loops I think there is a need for `appsecret_proof`. However, it generates that code itself and it gives invalid error. I don't know what to do.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
   'app_id' => '60...

]);

$feed = $graphNode->getField('feed')

while(true) {

   foreach ($feed->all() as $key1 => $post) {
     if ($likes = $post->getField('likes')){
       while(true) {
         if (!($likes = $fb->next($likes))) break;
       }
     } 
    }
   if (!($feed = $fb->next($feed))) break;
}
```

Comment: You need a `GraphEdge` to paginate via `next` method; but I doubt if `getField('likes')` actually returns a `GraphEdge` – can you verify that via a var_dump output? Check the example for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0#next – see how they are explicitly working with GraphEdges there? Try and implement it in the same way.

Comment: `$feed->all()` returns all items for a feed which are post. `$post` is node and to get `likes` field we can't use array index like `arr['likes']`, this does not work, instead we use `getField()` function which is defined in `Collection.php`, each likes items is `GraphEdge` object so there is no problem.

Comment: What is your initial `$graphNode`, how did you create it?

Comment: `$response = $fb->get('/259454320877898?fields=feed.limit(5){message,from,likes{name,picture},is_popular,created_time,updated_time}');`  Next iterator properly works for feed but not works for likes. [Here](http://www.takwing.idv.hk/blog/2013/be-careful-with-latest-php-sdk-v3-2-2-on-appsecret_proof/) it points to `appsecret_proof` for loops.

Comment: I think you will need to get the `/likes` edge for the individual posts first, otherwise it won’t work. Try requesting `/259454320877898/feed` instead, and request details for the individual posts afterwards.

Comment: I will check endpoints, but i don't think it uses `/feed` for deeper requests.

Comment: `getField('likes')` returns the `likes` edge and it has a `next` attribute starts like `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/259454320877898_519700344853293/likes?..` so I think there is a problem with endpoint here. When I access next url from browser it works properly.

Comment: Well if that very same `next` URL works when copy&pasted into the browser, then it’s likely the SDK that messes it up somehow. In that case, I’d suggest you file a bug report and ask Facebook to fix it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Ok, I will report it, thanks.

Comment: When I decrease the limits for `feed` and `likes` the problem solved. So the working url is like that `$fb->get('/259454320877898?fields=feed.limit(2){message,from,likes.limit(2){name,picture}‌​,is_popular,created_time,updated_time}');`

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this just should break or not depending on different limit values (before you did specify a limit for likes as well, I think the default should have been 25) – so I’d say this is definitively worth filing a bug report.

Comment: I reported bug but closed it after solution. I am hesitant to reopen it.

Comment: Problem started again, I will report it as a bug.